# Weird battery behavior with new battery - Moto x 2nd gen

Tags: battery, moto-x

I have a Moto X 2nd gen (2014) that I got about 2 years ago. The battery has been failing recently and was dying at around 20 to 30%. I ordered a new battery on ebay that claimed to be genuine (It's label looked identical to the battery that came out of the phone). After replacing the battery, it has been dying around 60 to 70%. I have followed the instructions outlined [here](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-calibrate-the-battery-on-your-android-device) to no avail. After dying around 70%, I leave the phone off and charge it. It starts at 0% and goes to around 30% where it lingers awhile (1 to 2 hours) before jumping to 100%. Any idea what is causing the issue? I don't believe it to be an old battery dressed as new because these 2nd gen Moto X batteries come out bent/curved and the new one was flat. Any further steps I can take before ordering a different one? Could a factory reset help?

Thank you.

Edit: Here's a screenshot after it's hung around 30% (at 34%) for awhile on the app Ampere. It has cell voltage and charging current. It seems like the voltage is to high for 34% and the charging current is too slow... [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QKqKiUEAstlD7pPBHhcJivpPdhMFCmQUBg)

Comment: I've seen jumping charges on my tablet. The most common incident is simply a bad driver.

Comment: It didn't jump like that when charging the original battery though...